# Increase width of the caption in threeparttable

Tags: tables, captions, threeparttable

I wonder how to restore width of the caption in `threeparttable` environment to regular `table` environment. It is important that caption is inside `threeparttable` environment. In other words I want to increase caption width (Figure 1).

[image]

The minimal working example goes as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{threeparttable,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{This is example table with width equal to default width in table environment}
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
\toprule
Col 1& Col 2 & Col 3 & Col 4 \\
\midrule
1 &  2 &  3 &  4 \\
5 &  6 &  7 &  8 \\
9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]\footnotesize
\item[1] Long, long, long, long, long, long, note
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

When I insert `\renewcommand\TPTminimum{\linewidth}` before `\caption{...}` the width extends, but the table in left aligned (Figure 2 below).

[image: Figure2]

Any suggestion or pointer is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why is it important that the caption is inside `threeparttable`?

Comment: @egreg Because I need to put footnote also in the caption.

Comment: The environment basically typesets a `\vbox` where the `\hsize` is the maximum between the table width and `\TPTminimum`.

Comment: You can move the caption outside `threeparttable`, but still inside `table`.

Comment: @MichaelPalmer Now I use `\caption{This is example table with width equal \ldots\tnote{a}}` outside the `threeparttable`. However, the notes are printed below the table but the footnote mark in caption is omitted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The macro `\tnote` is defined in such a way that it will not function outside the `threeparttable` environment.  This is mostly to prevent it from showing up in the `\listoftables`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{threeparttable,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\listoftables

\begin{table}
\let\TPToverlap=\TPTrlap
\centering
\caption{This is example table with width equal to default width in table 
  environment\tnote{1}}
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
\toprule
Col 1& Col 2 & Col 3 & Col 4 \\
\midrule
1 &  2 &  3 &  4 \\
5 &  6 &  7 &  8 \\
9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]\footnotesize
\item[1] Long, long, long, long, long, long, note
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo 1]

---

If you also want the notes wider, you can put the `tabular` inside another `tabular`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{threeparttable,booktabs}

\newlength{\mymargin}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{This is example table with width equal to default width in table 
  environment\tnote{1}}
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{\textwidth}@{}}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
\toprule
Col 1& Col 2 & Col 3 & Col 4 \\
\midrule
1 &  2 &  3 &  4 \\
5 &  6 &  7 &  8 \\
9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]\footnotesize
\item[1] Long, long, long, long, long, long, note
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo 2]